# Is Squeeze-theorem needed in this case?

Tags: limits

So I'm going learning Calculus 1 from udemy (Become a Calculus 1 Master) and at the squeeze theorem there's an example which I can't understand why did she use the squeeze theorem at all. The problem looks like:

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x^{3}+\sin(4x)}{6x^{3}+5} $$

Can't we just solve it like we solve any limits at infinity?

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x^{3}+\sin(4x)}{6x^{3}+5} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2*\frac{x^{3}}{x^{3}}+\sin(4x)*\frac{x^{0}}{x^{3}}}{6*\frac{x^{3}}{x^{3}} + 5*\frac{x^{0}}{x^{3}}} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2*x^{0}+\frac{\sin(4x)}{x^{3}}}{6*x^{0}+\frac{5}{x^{3}}} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2*1+\frac{\sin(4x)}{x^{3}}}{6*1+\frac{5}{x^{3}}} $$

Now, since $x$ goes to positive infinity and $-1 \leq  \sin(k) \leq +1$, then:

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x^{3}+\sin(4x)}{6x^{3}+5} = \frac{2+\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sin(4x)}{x^{3}}}{6+\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{5}{x^{3}}} = \frac{2}{6} $$

This seems okay to me unless I completely missed something. But instead of doing this, she uses the squeeze theorem to come to the same result. Am I missing something, or the squeeze theorem is not needed?

Comment: Maybe the intent was to let you become familiar with the squeeze theorem and practice. Are you able to solve by squeezing ?

Comment: Once you state that $-1 \leq sin(k) \leq 1$, you're implicitly using the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{2x^{3}+\sin(4x)}{6x^{3}+5}-\frac13=\frac{3\sin(4x)-5}{3(6x^3+5)}.$$

You easily obtain a bracketing by noting that the numerator lies in $[-8,-2]$.